# Extra white space strip on iPhone5 mobile web development

Tags: css, safari

I'm wondering why my page on iPhone 5 displays a white strip on the right side. It doesn't happen for iPhone 6 and higher, just on a smaller iPhone 5 screen it shows. I've tried search my CSS for any min-width incongruencies or any possible CSS errors but haven't been able to find a solution, the Call Us Now is a fixed div -- I just don't understand how the body is not encompassing 100% of the screen for iPhone 5 display. Any help is appreciated. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtiYK.png)

Comment: you can show your code here using code pan. also you can debug your app using Safari Technology Preview https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had a bunch of absolute elements opacity 0, and also images that surpassed the screen size, so I had to minimize the image and style the absolute elements left:0